# Mp3 / Wav to Text

Tags: speech-to-text, lync

I currently have a mobile application that can record speech as either a WAV or MP3 and would like to convert it to text.  I have looked around - Microsoft Speech, UCMA, etc -- but haven't seen any good examples of how to do it.  Can someone help out here?

FYI - We have access to MS Lync.

Look forward to any responses,
James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a sample of using the UCMA 3.0 SDK to perform speech recognition, available [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Using-VoiceXML-in-a-UCMA-560116d2). However, from experience (and I've love to be proved wrong here) you can only recognise a specific response from a pre-determined set of options. So, you can ask "How was your day" and tell UCMA that valid responses are "Good", "Fair", "Bad" and it will then attempt to match any of those. I've not seen it be able to 'just' do free-speech conversion. (a much harder problem)

This might be something the Microsoft Speech API can do better. Try [this post](http://www.codestrider.com/BlogRead.aspx?b=62772cb1-acd2-4935-acae-2356c43421ad) for a head start.