# convert music file to text frequencies, to use at beep (pcspkr)

Tags: linux

I am trying to convert a .wav music file into something playable at `beep` command.

I need to export the frequencies to a text format to use as input parameters at `beep`.

Ps.: It is not about [Speech Transcription](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123588/mp3-wav-to-text).

Comment: You have to use the samples in the .wav file and do a fourier transform to get the frecuency components, but you'll get a lot of frecuencies.  It's not clear what you want from the explanation you give.  Do you know anything about digital signal processing?  What `beep` command do you mean?

Comment: @LuisColorado finally found a good example, [I mean this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wu5zd5fCaPA). Clearly sounds like a limited thing. May be, [converting a wav into 1bit](http://shiru.untergrund.net/1bit/pivot/entry.php?id=162) could do the trick (I dont mean quality, I mean to have something working good enough to be usable).

Comment: mmm.. the flaw may be "piezoelectric beeper instead of a real electromagnetic speaker" is required, at the end of [here](http://shiru.untergrund.net/1bit/pivot/entry.php?id=162). All actual computers probably have piezo speakers... so this may never work.

Comment: I found some players for wav [here](http://spkcorner.tripod.com/spkdos.htm).

Comment: mmm... using `dosemu` (that direcly access the pc-speaker), and using [lxvox](http://spkcorner.tripod.com/lxvox.zip) found [here](http://spkcorner.tripod.com/spkdos.htm), the sound was unintelligible, I think the problem is my speaker is piezoelectric. But using `doxbox`, that simulated the pc-speaker thru my headphones, it actually sounds like someone speaking (with some horrible noises, but still intelligible).

Comment: aww sorry, was researching, I mean this [beep command](http://linux.die.net/man/1/beep)

Answer (score 0):

The beep command in linux is only to control de pc-speaker.  It only allows one frequency simultaneously and doesn't apply.  A wav file is a file of samples that normally carries music (music is made of a lot of simultaneous frequencies)

You cannot convert a wav file to play it on the pc-speaker.  You need a sound card to do that.

As you say, it's not voice recognition, but even in that case, a violin simple note sounds different than a guitar one, because it carries not only a single frequency in it.  There are what is called harmonics, different components at different frequencies (normally multiples of the original frequency) that makes the sound different (not only the frequencies matter, also the relative intensities of them)  and that is impossible to reproduce with a tool that only allows you to play a single frequency, with a given shape (the wave is not sinusoidal, but have several already included harmonics, that make it sound like a pc speaker) and no intensity capable.

Comment: Cool info. Anyway, here is a link about [making music with the single instrument internal pc speaker](https://www.kirrus.co.uk/2010/09/linux-beep-music/). I will add a link to old pc internal speaker music (yes bad sounding music but still music) as soon I find it.

Comment: May be, if the wav data could be simplified, it could fit in a single instrument frequency. [This is what they did in old times](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wyXBESSgakM)(there is an even better example, but I still need to find it..), but I think it was all coded by hand, and not converted from a natural music.

Comment: @AquariusPower, of course you can, but you must know about fourier transforms and some signal processing to do that.  Even in that case, the solution might not be good and need some retouching by hand.  In this case, it's not an objective conversion, you have to lose a lot of info in the process and you have to decide which is important and which not.